# rxjs - delay function return until a stream value meets a condition and is unsubscribed

Tags: angular, reactjs, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have a method that is triggering a server request. It has access to a stream from the redux-store and should execute a callback as soon as the result of the request is found in the mentioned stream. So basically:

```
private resultStream$: Observable<boolean>;
doFetch(args, callback) {
    store.dispatchHttpRequest(args);
    // this should only be executed when resultStream$ emits true
    callback();
}
```

How do I make `callback();` to be called only when `resultStream$` emits true AND I have unsubscribed from the stream, so there is no memory leak?

I have tried `takeWhile()`, putting the `dispatchHttpRequest` the setter of a conditional (for takeWhile) and the callback itself in the `subscription()` but it seems I am doing something wrong because I get bugs in my app. To be precise, the callback is only executed when `doFetch()` is called more than once, so the first request receives no callback-response.

Comment: What is the relation between the call to dispatchHttpRequest and the resultStream? How is this call relevant to the question?

Comment: resultStream$ is just an example. In my app it is not a boolean but an object that is compared for being the right response to the request or not.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: 'I have tried takeWhile(), putting the dispatchHttpRequest the setter of a conditional (for takeWhile)'. - this implies dispatchHttpRequest returns an observable, which is not the most usual pattern. Could you please post this action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
private resultStream$: Observable<boolean>;
doFetch(args, callback) {
    this.resultStream$.filter(r => r).take(1).subscribe(e => callback());

    store.dispatchHttpRequest(args);
}
```

Comment: for some reason I still get no callback for the very first call of `doFetch()`, but the cause must be somewhere else in my application I guess. Thank you for confirming it. This version is also more elegant than takeWhile, I think.

Comment: hm weird, i mean this should definitely pick up any true event from resultStream$, don't know why it would need to run twice, does sound like someone else is holding it up for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `finally` which is called when the chain is disposed. This means when all observers unsubscribed or when the chain completed/errored.

```
private resultStream$: Observable<boolean>;

doFetch(args, callback) {
    store.dispatchHttpRequest(args);

    return this.resultStream
      // be aware that `takeWhile` completes when the predicate function returns false
      .takeWhile(val => !Boolean(val) /* or whatever ... */)
      .finally(() => callback());
}
```

If you know the chain is going to complete you don't need to unsubscribe yourself.